# Getting the unique count of strings from a text string

Tags: r, dplyr, tm, stringr

I am wondering on how to get the unique number of characters from the text string. Let's say I am looking for a count of repetition of the words apples, bananas,  pineapples, grapes in this string.

```
 A<- c('I have a lot of pineapples, apples and grapes. One day the pineapples person gave the apples person two baskets of grapes')

 df<- data.frame(A)
```

Let's say I want to get all the unique count of the fruits listed in the text.

```
  library(stringr)
  df$fruituniquecount<- str_count(df$A, "apples|pineapples|grapes|bananas")
```

I tried this but I get the over all count. I would like to the answer as '3'. Please suggest your ideas.

Comment: I think you have to look at the``tidytext`` pakcage. Here is a online book: [link](https://www.tidytextmining.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `str_extract_all` and then calculate the length of the unique elements.

Input:

```
A <- c('I have a lot of pineapples, apples and grapes. One day the pineapples person gave the apples person two baskets of grapes')
fruits <- "apples|pineapples|grapes|bananas"
```

Result

```
length(unique(c(stringr::str_extract_all(A, fruits, simplify = TRUE))))
# [1] 3
```

Comment: I am getting a strange error when I try this on my dataset and create a column called df$fruitcount. I have many rows and and the count is always given as 5. Can you please suggest if i am missing anything?

Comment: Please share the output of `dput(head(your_dataframe))` at the end of your question.

Comment: Yes I have added the data in the question and the expected output

Comment: @user3570187 This seems like a different story to me. As you received quite a few answers now I'd suggest you ask another one with the data that you just posted and accept / upvote the answers that solved this problem.

Comment: Agree with @markus that your edits should be a different question.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I posted another question.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly elegant, but you could use `str_detect` like this.

```
sum(str_detect(df$A, "apples"), 
    str_detect(df$A, "pineapples"), 
    str_detect(df$A, "grapes"), 
    str_detect(df$A, "bananas"))
```

Or, based on the comments below, if you put all these terms in their own vector you could then use an apply function:

```
fruits <- c("apples", "pineapples", "grapes", "bananas")
sum(sapply(fruits, function(x) str_detect(df$A, x)))
```

Comment: I am getting a strange error when I try this on my dataset and create a column called df$fruitcount. I have many rows and and the count is always given as very large number. Can you please suggest if i am missing anything?

Comment: This could be shortened to `sum(sapply(fruits, function(x) str_detect(df$A, x)))`, with `fruits <- c("apples", "pineapples", "grapes", "bananas")`.

Answer (score 3):

One base possibility could be:

```
length(unique(unlist(regmatches(A, gregexpr("apples|pineapples|grapes|bananas", A, perl = TRUE)))))

[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a better way to do this is by first breaking down the words and then getting the count.

```
library(tokenizers)
library(magrittr)
df$fruituniquecount <- tokenize_words(A) %>% unlist(.) %>% unique(.) %>% 
       stringr::str_count(., "apples|pineapples|grapes|bananas") %>% sum(.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Could also do:

```
A <- c('I have a lot of pineapples, apples and grapes. One day the pineapples person gave the apples person two baskets of grapes')

df <- data.frame(A) 

fruits <- c("apples", "pineapples", "grapes", "bananas")

df$count <- sum(tolower(unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$A), "\\.|,| ")))) %in% fruits)
```

Output:

```
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is a regex-less base R solution as well,

```
sum(unique(strsplit(A, ' ')[[1]]) %in% c('apples', 'pineapples', 'grapes', 'bananas'))
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a combination of `stringr` and `stringi`:

```
target<-"apples|pineapples|grapes|bananas"#inspired by @markus ' solution
length(stringi::stri_unique(stringr::str_extract_all(A,target,simplify=TRUE)))
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel?  The **quanteda** package is built for this.

Define a vector of your fruits, which as a bonus I've used with the (default) [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) pattern match type to catch both singular and plural forms.

```r
A <- c("I have a lot of pineapples, apples and grapes. One day the pineapples person gave the apples person two baskets of grapes")
fruits <- c("apple*", "pineapple*", "grape*", "banana*")

library("quanteda", warn.conflicts = FALSE)
## Package version: 1.4.2
## Parallel computing: 2 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
```

Then once you have tokenized this into words using `tokens()`, you can send the result to `tokens_select()` using your vector `fruits` to select just those types.

```r
toks <- tokens(A) %>%
  tokens_select(pattern = fruits)
toks
## tokens from 1 document.
## text1 :
## [1] "pineapples" "apples"     "grapes"     "pineapples" "apples"    
## [6] "grapes"
```

Finally, `ntype()` will tell you the number of word *types* (unique words), which is your desired output of 3.

```r
ntype(toks)
## text1 
##     3
```

Alternatively you could have counted non-unique occurrences, known as *tokens*.

```r
ntoken(toks)
## text1 
##     6
```

Both functions are vectorized to return a named integer vector where the element name will be your document name (here, the **quanteda** default of "text1" for the single document), so this also works easily and efficiently on a large corpus.

**Advantages?**  Easier (and more readable) than regular expressions, plus you have access to additional function for tokens.  For instance, let's say you wanted to consider singular and plural fruit patterns as equivalent.  You could do this in two ways in **quanteda**: through replacing the pattern with a canonical form manually using `tokens_replace()`, or by stemming the fruit names using `tokens_wordstem()`.

Using `tokens_replace()`:

```r
B <- "one apple, two apples, one grape two grapes, three pineapples."

toksrepl <- tokens(B) %>%
  tokens_select(pattern = fruits) %>%
  tokens_replace(
    pattern = fruits,
    replacement = c("apple", "pineapple", "grape", "banana")
  )
toksrepl
## tokens from 1 document.
## text1 :
## [1] "apple"     "apple"     "grape"     "grape"     "pineapple"
ntype(toksrepl)
## text1 
##     3
```

Using `tokens_wordstem()`:

```r
toksstem <- tokens(B) %>%
  tokens_select(pattern = fruits) %>%
  tokens_wordstem()
toksstem
## tokens from 1 document.
## text1 :
## [1] "appl"     "appl"     "grape"    "grape"    "pineappl"
ntype(toksstem)
## text1 
##     3
```